Write to tiff pages in parallel
Writing to multiple tiff pages is usually suggested as:

write all tiles of the first page
close the directory
write all tiles of the second page
close the directory
etc.
I am generating high resolution data for one image and I need to write the tiles as I generate them because the total image is too large.  I also want to generate the pyramid pages at the same time.  My plan is to:
write a row of tiles to the first page
write a second row of tiles to the first page
create a row of reduced resolution tiles
write these tiles to the second page
write a third row of tiles to the first page
write a forth row of tiles to the first page
create a row of reduced resolution tiles
write a row of reduced tiles to the second page
create a row of reduced resolution tiles from the two rows from the second page
write a row of reduced tiles to the third page.
etc.
This algorithm extends deeper but only buffers two rows from each page.  It requires keeping the directories open.
Can I do this with libtiff?

I can write pyramidal tiled images but only with the first method.  I don't yet see a way to set the page destination before each write of a tile.
